# Angular export csv multiple value field

Tags: angular, export-to-csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvJDF.png)
Hello,
As you can see on the third field of the CSV the values are separated and surrounded with hooks and quotation marks.
this is my code to export:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSxLU.png)
Thank you

How can I have something like this when I export(with commas only):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UHmf.png)

Comment: Please provide the code as text in a code block, not in an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `join` method, instead of the `map` method.

So replace this:

```js
"Training:"training.map(({label})) => (label))
```

With this:

```js
"Training":training.join();
```